# Unexpected Attribute Error when running the given python code

Tags: python, object

How can I effectively debug a Python script that's raising an 'AttributeError' on a seemingly valid object attribute access? I've checked the object's class definition and verified that the attribute exists, but I'm still encountering this error. What are some strategies or tools I can use to track down the root cause of this issue?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.data.append(item)

def main():
    obj = MyClass()
    obj.add_item("apple")
    obj.add_item("banana")

    for item in obj.items:
        print(item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried to debug my code using the PyCharm Debugger but nothing seemed to work! I am really stuck with this problem pls help

Comment: Typo: `obj.items` instead of `obj.data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.data.append(item)

def main():
    obj = MyClass()
    obj.add_item("apple")
    obj.add_item("banana")

    # Change 'obj.items' to 'obj.data'
    for item in obj.data:
        print(item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Replace `obj.items` with `obj.data` in the loop to access the correct attribute and fix the `AttributeError`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions about problems that are caused by a typo are off-topic on Stack Overflow, and should be closed instead of answered. Next time, click the "flag" button under the question, and select "Needs improvement" > "Community specific reason" > "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Also note that some people also downvote answers to off-topic questions, and having many negatively received answers can lead to an answer ban

Comment: I am sorry if I just wanted to provide an answer for an obviously new programmer and not just harshly report it...

Comment: You can always add a comment below the question once you have enough reputation. But questions like this a considered harmful to the site since they go against its purpose of being a repository of high quality Q&A. Questions need to be useful to future visitors, which questions that are caused typos are not. There's nothing wrong with asking for or giving help to new programmers, this just isn't the site for that.

Comment: Then I know what to do next time... thank you